# How to emit an event and send an array to parent from modal component

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js

In my vue application I have a modal where the content is another component (child) and sends an array to its parent component and the parent displays it. I had done this with props which works, but learned it is called an anti.patern and is not recommended. So I wanted to try it with events now. But I am kinda failing. I did the function to emit an event which calls the Method which fills the array with data. I binded the event with @ in my parent but there is no reaction or to be more precise the value from the event is undefined.

Could someone look at it and tell me what is wrong. I am new to vue and events so I am a bit lost:

Child Event Method:

```
      generateGroup(){
    var pageURL = window.location.href;
    var lastURLSegment = pageURL.substr(pageURL.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
     const newMeeting = {meetingUrl: "", meetingName: "", date: this.selectedDate, startTime: "", endTime: ""};
      newMeeting.meetingUrl = "https://jitsi.zim.uni-due.de/" + this.randomUrlIdGenerator().toString()
      newMeeting.meetingName = lastURLSegment
    this.model.forEach((model, i) => {
      const key = `participant${i + 1}`;
      newMeeting[key] = model.voterUniqueName;
      newMeeting.startTime = model.startTime;
      newMeeting.endTime = model.endTime
    })

    this.newGroup = [],
    this.finalMeetingArray.push(newMeeting)
    this.newGroup.push(newMeeting)
    return this.newGroup


  },

  eventSetter(){
    this.$emit('updateArray', this.generateGroup())
    this.newGroup = []
    this.selectedDate = ""
    this.model = []
  }

  eventSetter(){
    this.$emit('updateArray', this.generateGroup())
    this.newGroup = []
    this.selectedDate = ""
    this.model = []
  }
```

Parent html: this is where I am trying to bind my event and call a function:

```
  <AddGroupsModal @updateArray="generateGroup" ref="addGroupModal"/>
```

Method:

```
generateGroup(value){
      if(this.meetingArrayBackend.length === 0){
        console.log(this.meetingArrayBackend)
        let lastElement = this.value
            this.meetingsArray.concat(this.value)
        console.log("THIS.MEETING WIRD GEPUSHT INHALT : " + this.value)
      } else
      {
        let lastElement = this.value[this.value.length - 1]
        console.log(value)
        this.meetingsArray.push(lastElement)
      }

          console.log(JSON.stringify(this.meetingsArray))
    },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
return setTimeout(() => { this.newGroup.push(newMeeting) })
```

This is what you return from a function you call in the `emit`, if you want to get the data sent by this function to the event that is captured by the parent component you have to return a value, at this point you either do a `setTimeout` before this, and then return the value, but i don't think you need it. just return the value you want to receive in the parent component, now i have no clue from the context that you gave what you want there, but I am guessing you want to have the `newGroup` so you can do a:

```
this.newGroup.push(newMeeting) 
return this.newGroup
```

This should get you the data in the  `@updateArray` event.

Next problem, `@updateArray="generateGroup2()"` is not correct this actually means/ roughly translates to:

```
((paramsFromEmit) => generateGroup2())();
```

It should be: `@updateArray="generateGroup2"`, which will mean:

```
 generateGroup2(paramsFromEmit);
```

This is what you want called, this will get you the value you emitted in the `generateGroup2` function, when the emit triggers this event. It is pretty hard to understand the subtle difference between these two when you have it written down in the template but I hope this helped you understand it more.

Now, I do not really understand what you are trying to do in `generateGroup2`, but I will let you figure that out, my answer will get you the data from child to parent, and into `generateGroup2`, if you need any more help, feel free to ask. Also, please for the love of all that's holy, don't use `setTimeout`s please :D